# Connect to Azure SQL database in Node via mssql

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We are using Azure SQL Database at backend and Azure App Service for hosing Apis written in Node.

For connection we are using **mssql** package.

Code:

```
var mssql = require("mssql");

azureConnection = {
        user: '***',
        password: '***',
        server: '***.database.windows.net', 
        database: '***',
        options : {
            encrypt : true
        }
};

router.get('/BU', function(req, res, next) {
    mssql.close()
    mssql.connect(azureConnection, function (err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            mssql.close()
            next(err); 
        } 

        var request = new mssql.Request();

        var query = "Select Distinct(BU_Id) , BU_Name  from ***_data"  

        request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) {
                mssql.close()
                next(err); 
            } 
            res.locals.data = recordset["recordsets"][0]
            mssql.close()
            next();

        });
    });

}, response );
```

Now,the problem is that we get frequent HTTP 3xx, HTTP 5xx and Service Unavailable in response. Apis are falling like anything.

Please Help..!!

Comment: Debug your application and identify the line that fails and why. Add logging to your application and log possible errors instead of ignoring them. SQL Server doesn't return any HTTP codes. It's impossible to guess what's wrong when you don't provide any information. For all anyone knows, you may not *have* a `nokia_data` table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess there is some problem with connection mechanism

Comment: Don't guess. Debug your application. Log the errors. How do you expect anyone to help when you provide *no* information? Why do you even assume it's the database connection at fault? 3xx status codes are about *redirection*. You may be using the wrong URL or credentials to connect to your application

Comment: BTW if you check the [package's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) you'll notice that the code is *very, very* different from your own. Your code can *easily* leave connections open or try to close non-existent connections.

Comment: And, you imported the package as `sql` but call it as `mssql`. Did you try debuggin this code at all? Just try to connect to a local database?

Comment: The docs have examples that show how to use the package with [callbacks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#callbacks) , [async/await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait), [promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises).